# How do you SUM two fields from two tables, even when the field in the second table could be null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following tables:

**products.rb**

```
# has_many :sales           

+----+----------+----------+-------+
| id | name     | quantity | price |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
| 1  | Pencil   | 30       | 1.0   |
| 2  | Pen      | 50       | 1.5   |
| 3  | Notebook | 100      | 2.0   |
+----+----------+----------+-------+
```

**sales.rb**

```
# belongs_to :product

+----+----------+------------+
| id | quantity | product_id |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  | 10       | 1          |
| 2  | 2        | 1          |
| 3  | 5        | 1          |
| 4  | 2        | 2          |
| 5  | 10       | 2          |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I'd like to know, first, how many items I have left, regardless of their type. The answer is of course 151, but that'd be cheating. I could simply make a SUM of both tables individually, then put them together to know the final number, but I'm wondering if this could be done via activerecord in a single command.

I tried the following:

```
Product.includes(:sales).group('products.id').sum('products.quantity - sales.quantity')
```

but I get:

```
=> {1=>73, 2=>88, 3=>0}
```

which is understandable, as it is going through each one to do the sum like this:

```
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
| products.quantity | sales.quantity | sum |
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
|        30         |       10       |  20 |
|        30         |        2       |  28 |
|        30         |        5       |  25 |
+-------------------+----------------+-----+
```

which equals 73.

Anyway, how could this be achieved with ActiveRecord? I want to know the total number of items, but I'd also like to know the total of each type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar of any `ActiveRecord` way to achieve what you want but you can try mixing a little sql in there

```
Product
  .group('products.id')
  .sum('products.quantity - (SELECT SUM(sales.quantity) AS sales_quantity FROM sales WHERE sales.product_id = products.id)')
```